# Implementing a model of a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I am just starting out with rails and have run into a little issue.  What I am trying to implement is a way to allow users to create "pages" on which they can tack on widgets.

So I have set up a model for "pages", which has database fields such as name, description etc. It also has a "has_many :widgets" association.

Here is where I am stumped.  I have a list of widgets users can use.  Things such as "about me", "photo gallery", "comments", "videos", etc.  They can chose one of these, customize the contents and add to their page.

i figure, when the user picks and customizes a widget I will add an entry into the widgets table with "belongs_to user_id".  However, I need to specify which widget the user chose and the custom contents entered.

How do I implement this in Rails?  Where can I define each widget type?

I can think of a few ways, but not sure which one is the best.

- One option is to use a model per widget.  I would have AboutMeWidget, VideosWidget, etc.  This will allow me to customize each model with whatever fields the widget might need.  However, this doesn't seem to be efficient and will require too many models.
- Another option is to define the widget types somewhere (but where?) and then simplify the "widget_type" in the widgets table.  (Therefore the table will contain "belongs_to :user" and "has_one :widget_type".)  I will also have to have a field for the data the user entered (probably through XML?).
- Last option I can think of is to use Ruby classes to define the widgets.  When the user customized the widget, I will create an object from the widget's class and store that object.

Is there another better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the specific fields for a given widget implementation don't need to be searchable I'd be tempted to put them into a serialized field.

```
class Page << AR
  has_many :embedded_widgets
  has_many :widgets, :through => :embedded_widgets
end

class Widget << AR
  has_many :embedded_widgets
end

class AboutMeWidget << Widget
class VideosWidget << Widget
... etc ...

class EmbeddedWidget << AR
  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :widget
  serializes :data
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Philip.  I haven't used has_many with a "through" so I'm having a hard time picturing how this would work.  What is the purpose of the Page model having "has_many :widgets, :through => :embedded_widgets"?  If I understand correctly, all this achieves is it lets me do something like Page.find(2).widgets.  But all I care about when I have a particular page are the embeddedwidgets on that page.  Since EmbeddedWidget has a "belongs_to :widget" I can then do "Page.find(2).embeddedwidgets.widget which will tell me what kind it is.

Comment: You might not need the Page.has_many.widgets at all.  But if you have a situation in which you just want the names of the widgets a page belongs to without the custom field info, that would do it.